# AWS EKS recommended PODs size

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, cost-management

Whats the best approach to find optimal pods size and EC2 machine types based on observed usage.

Is there a standard tool we can use to get recommendations and optimise cost?

Comment: I think it's more important to think about your stack and your app behavior than the Pod size as a general recommendation.

Which stack are you running? We can help you at zcloud.ws support as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches you can take to find the optimal pod size and EC2 machine types based on observed usage. One approach is to use the AWS Compute Optimizer, which is a service that makes it easy to ensure you are using optimal EC2 instance types for your workloads in order to optimize performance and cost.

Another approach is to manually determine the number of pods an instance type can support by referring to the Amazon EKS recommended maximum Pods for each Amazon EC2 instance type. You can also consider factors such as the number of instances in a node group, operating system, hardware architecture, and maximum number of pods when choosing between instance types that are supported by Amazon EKS.

Comment: Thanks it looks like Compute Optimizer provides recommendations for the right CPU and memory settings for ECS tasks. That’s exactly what Im looking for however for EKS PODs.

Comment: KRR is a good solution, https://github.com/robusta-dev/krr for sizing pods. Kapenter will automatically provision nodes based on your pods resource requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy Cowan KRR looks good, to be tested!

Comment: Happy to help @MarcC. You might also want to look at https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-instance-calculator. It will give you a sense of how many pods you can run on different types of instances.